# Walrus operator in dict declaration

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, walrus-operator

I want to use the walrus operator in a dictionary declaration. However the `:` is propably causing a problem. I have a dictionary declaration nested in a list comprehension, but I don't want to decompose it into a simple for-loop (that would be a lazy answer). Is it even possible?

```
rows = [
    {
        'words': sorted(row_words, key=lambda x: x['x0']),
        'top': top := min(map(lambda x: x['top'], row_words)),
        'doctop': top + doctop_adj,
    } for row_words in doctop_clusters
]
```

Also this could be useful in some simple scenario.

```
foo = {
    'a': a := some_calculation(),
    'b': a * 8
}
```

**NOTE:** [walrus operator in dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452329/walrus-operator-in-dict-comprehension) doesn't answer my question because I don't have a condition where I can use the walrus operator. And the following approach is very unclean.

```
rows = [
    {
        'words': sorted(row_words, key=lambda x: x['x0']),
        'top': top,
        'doctop': top + doctop_adj,
    } for row_words in doctop_clusters 
    if top := min(map(lambda x: x['top'], row_words)) or True
]
```

Comment: You need to include it in brackets like the question does you link to does - `'a': (a := some_calculation()),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse?tab=profile) pointed out in the comments, the trick is to wrap it in parentheses `()`.

So the solution for the general scenario is simply:

```py
foo = {
    'a': (a := some_calculation()),
    'b': a * 8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the walrus operator in your case:

```
rows = [
    {
        'words': sorted(row_words, key=lambda x: x['x0']),
        'top': (top := min(map(lambda x: x['top'], row_words))),
        'doctop': top + doctop_adj,
    } for row_words in doctop_clusters
]
```